# Get an error using one component in another

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a simple component that contains an export function. I'm trying to use this component in another one. Unfortunately I get the error below - why?

Simple NavBar Component:

```
import * as React from "react";
...

export default function ButtonAppBar() {
return (
<Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
  <AppBar position="static">
    <Toolbar>
      <IconButton
        size="large"
        edge="start"
        color="inherit"
        aria-label="menu"
        sx={{ mr: 2 }}
      >
        <MenuIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        News
      </Typography>
      <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
 </Box>
 );
}
```

Main.js:

```
import React from "react";
import NavBar from "./NavBar.js";

export default function Main() {
return (
<>
  <NavBar></NavBar>
</>
);
}
```

got the error:

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Comment: As the warning suggests, you are using a hook outside a react component. So, it has to be inside the funtional component, before `return` statement. Anything that starts with `use` will be treated as a hook by React.

Comment: Where is the import AppBar? And what is mean with ... ? If you ask me  This error not appear from Main.js and ButtonAppBar dont use any hook. Maybe this error's source from AppBar component

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a hook outside of these components.

According to the code snippet that you have provided, none of the components have any hooks called.

Make sure all hooks are used inside functional components.